# Windows doesn't detect when I plug an HDMI cable in

Tags: windows-7, hdmi

My HDMI isn't working - Windows no longer seems to notice when I put a cable in my laptop's HDMI port. I have Windows 7, running on a Packard Bell EN TS11HR (serial number 14012532016, if it helps).

I already installed all the drivers from Nvidia and Intel, and it doesn't help. I remember finding a solution to this issue on SU, involving writing something to the registry, but I can't seem to find it anymore now that the issue appeared again.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not add "answers" to questions that don't actually provide an answer -- Super User isn't a discussion forum! If you require clarification of an answer, post a comment ("add comment") instead. If you need to change something about your question, e.g. to add new information, *edit* it.

Answer (score 1):

If it was working before, and it stopped working suddenly without any system configs alteration, then most likely its a hardware (cable) issue.

Do you have a certified HDMI cable? Sometimes cheap replicas fail out of a sudden.

To troubleshoot the problem, try to connect your computer to a different hdmi-device with the same cable OR try a different computer to the same device with the same cable. That way you'll get a better idea what is not working.

---

Check out my question, I had a similar problem there:

[Sudden “No Signal” in HDMI-DVI connection](https://superuser.com/questions/665018/sudden-no-signal-in-hdmi-dvi-connection/665433)

Comment: yes it is a hardware cable issue ..
you have to set it in windows registry !

Comment: If its a hardware issue, than altering windows registry will not help. You have to physically check the cable, test it with other device, etc